# How do I retrieve the different column's text of same row of html table?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table

I have a table in which I have a column with a hyperlink. Now one more column holds some value. My doubt is:
How can I detect which row's hyperlink is clicked and based on that how to retrieve the value at that row's other column?

For example structure will be like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>some_value</td>
<td>hyperlink</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>some_value</td>
<td>hyperlink</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>some_value</td>
<td>hyperlink</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So now if a user clicks on a hyperlink I need to retrieve the "some_value" of that row only.

This hyperlink is a link to another html page.When i click on that link i need to store the text of other column in local storage for further use in next html page.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a standard link with a variable in the parameter?

```
<tr>
<td>some value</td>
<td><a href="/page.php?id=some+value">hyperlink</a></td>
</tr>
```

This can be done some in an automated fashion with javascript and/or jQuery - but I don't see that you requested that. Here is a sample using jQuery.

```
<tr>
<td class="val">some value</td>
<td class="link">hyperlink</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.link').click(function(){
       var val = $(this).prev('.val').text();
       var url = 'page.php?value=' + val;
       alert(url);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working in my case…The hyperlink is nothing but a link to another html page…When going to that html page i need to have associated column's value stored in local storage..